# Save a function to NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So, I was wondering if it is possible to save a function to user defaults using Swift. For a string, for example, I would do this:

```
var inputData = "Hi"
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setValueForKey(inputData, forKey: "data")
```

Then to save it do a variable, I would say:

```
var gotData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.valueForKey("data")!
```

Now, my question is, if it is possible to save a function to user defaults. For example:

```
var inputData = func helloWorld(){println("Hello World!")}
```

Is it possible to then call that function that was saved to user defaults by doing something similar to .valueForKey ?

Any help is valued! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What happened when you tried it...

Comment: I think you are mixing up `valueForKey` and `objectForKey`.

Comment: Why would you even want to save function ? What is the benefit of saving it.

Comment: Save an enum and switch function according to its setting at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot save a function to `NSUserDefaults`.  From the *[NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html)*:

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of `NSData`.

A function is not any of the supported types, and as far as I know you cannot archive a function either.